# Jenkins Pipeline Job Build

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to build a Jenkins Pipeline job. I am trying to put sonarqube scanner configurations into Jenkins pipeline job's Groovy script. 
[image: Sonarqube configurations in Jenkins Pipeline Job Groovy Script]

But when I build the above job I get the following error-
[image: Error]

Also when I refer to Sonarqube documentation for integrating with Jenkins Pipeline job I get no information about setting the sonarqube properties which otherwise we have to set by adding a step - "execute sonarqube scanner"

[image]

Could anyone help in knowing how can we set the Sonarqube properties in jenkins pipeline job which otherwise we can specify in Maven or Freestyle Job Types in Jnekins (shown in above snapshot).
Thanks.

Now I have changes the Groovy script of Jenkins Pipeline Job configuration-
[image]

Now I am getting the error -

[image]

Could anyone please help me with the above issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration file is, in my case, always in the application repository and then called from the jenkins job as $WORKSPACE/sonar-project.properties

The content of the file is (example):

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=<project-key>
sonar.projectName=<project-name>
sonar.projectVersion=<project-version>

# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=src/vendor/**/*

# Language
sonar.language=php

# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.php.coverage.reportPath=src/coverage-clover.xml #change path to location of your test report
sonar.php.tests.reportPath=src/unitreport.xml  #change path to location of your test report
```

In Jenkins/Global tool configuration you must add a Sonarqube scanner, looks like this:

[image]

And in the manage Jenkins/Configure system  you must add your Sonarqube server "redacted Sonarqube" configured like this:

[image: Sonarqube config example]

In the job itself you have:

```
def scannerHome = tool 'azure-tools-sonarqube'  #This is the scanner you added

withSonarQubeEnv('redacted Sonarqube') {  #This is the server you added
  sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have all the configuartion for Sonarqube in  manage Jenkins/Configure system. Also The error i was facing was due to jdk1.7. After I updated it to jdk 1.8 the error was resolved. But now I am getting another error- Error during SonarQube Scanner execution ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources.
As you mentioned in your answer we can have these properties in sonar-project.properties but is there a way to directly specify these properties in Groovy Script.

Comment: You can define all the properies in the same execution step, prior to 'def scannerHome' line. Properties are the same as there would be in the config file:

            sonar.projectKey=<Project Key>
            sonar.projectName=<Project Name>
            sonar.projectVersion=1.0

            //# Comma-separated paths to directories with sources (required)
            sonar.sources=src
            sonar.exclusions=src/vendor/**/*

            //# Language
            sonar.language=php

            //# Encoding of the source files
            sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

The `unsupported major.minor version` error happens because you are not running with Java 1.8.
Can you double the version of Java is 1.8 on all slaves including the master where Jenkins is running?
`sonar-scanner` requires Java 1.8 and your `JAVA_HOME` variable must point to that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will be doing that. But could you also please tell me how to set sonarqube properties in jenkins pipeline job.

Comment: this worked for me :  
 
    node {
    def scannerHome = tool 'SONARQUBE';
    echo scannerHome;
    withSonarQubeEnv {
        sh "echo test"
        
    }
    }

Try this script, make sure you have a tool in Jenkins -> Global Tool Configuration -> sonarqube scanner and name it SONARQUBE

Comment: I did change java to java1.8 and i stopped getting the above error.Thanks. But now i am getting the error - ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
ERROR: You must define the following mandatory properties for 'Unknown': sonar.projectKey, sonar.projectName, sonar.projectVersion, sonar.sources
I am getting the error as I am not setting the above mentioned properties. But how do we set those properties in Pipeline job?

Comment: @YuganderKrishanSingh i think you have to set these in global tools configuration -> Sonar Scanner

Comment: if I set these properties in Global tools configuration then these properties will be fixed. But I have a number of keys for different projects. So then how will I be using separate keys.